# Get failed jobs by date range in Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

I need to get a list of failed jobs in the last hour as part of health checks. After some searching I came up with this

```
var failedCount = hangfireMonitoringApi.FailedCount();
hangfireMonitoringApi.FailedJobs(0, (int)failedCount)
                .Where(j => j.Value.FailedAt <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1))
                .ToList();
```

Will Hangfire apply the where clause at the database query level, or get all failed jobs from db and filter in memory? What's the recommended way to get the failed jobs for a given a time range?

Comment: The code you've provided will first retrieve all failed jobs from the database and then perform filtering in memory, not at the database level. The Where clause is being applied to the list of failed jobs after it has been retrieved from the database.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected the same... What would be the best way to get the failed jobs within a date range?